# Should I still use tf.estimator.Estimator if I don't have labels?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a Neural Network problem where I know the derivative of the error function with respect to my output, but not the target value (such a thing doesn't make sense in this problem). I could of course created one by adding the gradient to the output and then using a DNNEstimator, but this seems contrived.

A simplified example might be training a neural network to position a square in Cartesian space such that it does not overlap with another square whose coordinates are the input. In such a scenario we can easily compute a derivative (to move away from the center of the other square) but a label makes no sense.

Tensorflow's [page on Estimators](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/custom_estimators) makes it sound like *not* using Estimators is generally a bad idea:

> You can create a custom Estimator to do just about anything. If you
>   want hidden layers connected in some unusual fashion, write a custom
>   Estimator. If you want to calculate a unique metric for your model,
>   write a custom Estimator. Basically, if you want an Estimator
>   optimized for your specific problem, write a custom Estimator.

Ok, but Tensorflow's `tf.estimator.Estimator` class seems to be tightly coupled to the notion that features must be accompanied by labels, as per the signature of `model_func`:

```
def my_model_fn(
   features, # This is batch_features from input_fn
   labels,   # This is batch_labels from input_fn
   mode,     # An instance of tf.estimator.ModeKeys
   params):  # Additional configuration
```

But I don't have any labels. Does it still make sense for me to use a custom Estimator in this case, or am I better off just using the lower level APIs directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use the Estimator API. You just need to return a  [tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EstimatorSpec). During training, it would look like this:

```
tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions, loss, trainOp)
```

where trainOp is typically the result of an optimization step (this is where your error function derivative would be used).

You can also use the lower level APIs but you would lose all the advantages of the Estimator API, which, for example, allow you to export your trained model easily for inference serving.

Comment: what should I do regarding the "labels" parameter on the `input_fn` and `model_fn`? Do I just pass in bogus values?

Comment: You can set the label to None when returning from input_fn, and keep the parameter to None, in the model_fn. It doesn't need to be specified.

Comment: What about the `loss` parameter to the constructor of `EstimatorSpec`? Do I populate that with bogus values as well?

Comment: You need to specify a loss during training. It can easily be computed in the scenario you have given. In any case, you need some criteria for convergence. Error derivative isn't enough.